# Convert HTML Form to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

I want to convert a HTML Form to a JSON object. The form basically contains two sections, Header and Detail. The Header section contains some HTML Input boxes and the Detail section is a Table. A dummy view of my Form is as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <form id="MyForm" method="POST">
 <div name="HeaderData">
  <label id="lblFname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname"/> <br/>
  <label id="lblLname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/>
  <label id="lblEmail">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
 </div>
 <div id="DetailData">
  <table cellspacing="0" align="Center" rules="all" border="1" id="MyTable" style="width:940px;border-collapse:collapse;">
   </thead>  
     <th scope="col">Code</th>
     <th scope="col">Name</th>
     <th scope="col">Continent</th>
     <th scope="col">Region</th>
     <th scope="col">Population</th>
     <th scope="col">Independence Year</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td name="Code">Ind</td>
     <td name="Country">India</td>
     <td name="Continent">Asia</td>
     <td name="Region">Asia</td>
     <td name="Population">113Core</td>
     <td name="Independence">1947</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td name="Code">Ind</td>
     <td name="Country">India</td>
     <td name="Continent">Asia</td>
     <td name="Region">Asia</td>
     <td name="Population">1500000</td>
     <td name="Independence">1947</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

I would expect the resulting JSON object to mimic:

```js
{"HeaderData":[{"Fname":"XYZ","LName":"ABC","Email":"ABC@XYZ.COM"}],
 "DetailData":[{"Code":"Ind","Name":"India","Continent":"Asia","Region":"Asia","Population":"113 Crore","Independence Year":"1947"}],
 "DetailData":[{"Code":"Ind","Name":"India","Continent":"Asia","Region":"Asia","Population":"113 Crore","Independence Year":"1947"}]
}
```

I have tried different libraries like jquery.tabletojson.js but they are not able to assign arrays to separate variables.

Later I want to convert this JSON object to an XML String so that I can process it in a SQL Server QUERY. I would expect the XML String to mimic:

```html
enter code here
<Root>
 <HeaderData>
  <FName>XYZ</FName>
  <LName>XYZ</LName>
  <Email>abc@xyz.com</Email>
 </HeaderData>
 <DetailData>
  <Code>Ind</Code>
  <Name>India</Name>
  <Continent>Asia</Continent>
  <Region>Asia</Region>
  <Population>113Crore</Population>
  <IndependenceYear>1947</IndependenceYear>
 </DetailData>
 <DetailData>
  <Code>Ind</Code>
  <Name>India</Name>
  <Continent>Asia</Continent>
        <Region>Asia</Region>
  <Population>113Crore</Population>
  <IndependenceYear>1947</IndependenceYear>
 </DetailData>
</Root>
```

My current priority is building the JSON STRING. I can convert the data to XML once the JSON is available.

Comment: your json example makes no sense. you've got multiple items with the same name. that's not how json works.

Comment: Shouldn't the `DetailData` nodes in the XML be wrapped in a parent node?  (`DetailDatas` or something of that nature)

Comment: You might consider limiting your question to JSON. The fact that you want to convert the JSON to XML is superflous to your actual question. Your question will be easier to read.

Comment: Hi, Philip Raath, please be informed that here each detail section in the xml would actually be inserted as a row in table. Kindly suggest if you have a way out.

Answer (score 1):

if all your `<td>`'s have a name attribute you can convert it to an object with a few lines of jQuery...

```
var poop = [];
$("#MyTable").find("tr").each(function(){
    var fart = {};
    if(!$(this).find("td").length) return;
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        fart[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).text();
    });
    poop.push(fart);
});

console.log(poop);
```

[fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/aaompofn/)

Comment: whoever tried to edit the answer, please read the question before editing people's answers. this answer has absolutely nothing to do with a form.

Comment: Hi, Pootie, I have tried the option you provided. But its not fruitful. It returns the json object and arrays. but I want the arrays within variables